# How to share the same step definition across projects within same solution in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

- **SpecFlow Version:** [ x ] 2.2.1
- **Used Test Runner** [ x ]MSTest
- **Visual Studio Version** [ x ]VS 2017
- **Are the latest Visual Studio updates installed?** [ x ]Yes
- **.NET Framework:** [ x ] .NetCore 2.0
- **Test Execution Method:** [ x ]Visual Studio Test Explorer

  Section in app.config

**Repro Project**

I have a solution with multiple test projects under that as below

- InfoModelApiTests
- WarmDataTests

**Issue Description**

I want to use the same step as used in the *"InfoModelApiTests"* project feature file inside the *"WarmDataTests"* project's feature file. I don't want to repeat the step definition code. I have included the project reference of *"InfoModelApiTests"* in the *"WarmDataTests"* project. And added stepAssemblies reference in the app.config. But I am unable to get the step definition turning into black implying it's been binded.

The step definition class will look as below
public sealed class InfoModelApiTestsSteps

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Add the project reference of "InfoModelApiTests" in the
  "WarmDataTests" project
- Then in the app.config in "WarmDataTests" project add the
  StepAssemblies as mentioned above
- Copy the same step from the "InfoModelApiTests" feature file to
  "WarmDataTests" feature file. It should get binded to the existing
  step definition.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1194#issuecomment-402934038

---

You did it right.
The VS Extension has some problems with additional step assemblies and so the highlighting doesn't work correctly.
But when you execute the tests, it is working.

Comment: Thanks and the highlighting is working fine now. But when I tried executing the tests, I got the exception as below for the steps
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
I added the NUnit package and tried running again and ended up with the exception as below. (Anyway we use MsTest runner only)
NUnit.Framework.InconclusiveException: 'No matching step definition found for one or more steps.